# cannot login to the application after add IDbSet to ApplicationDbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

This is my ApplicationDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
   : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,
   string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationGroup> ApplicationGroups { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to run and login to my application browser shows this error

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

i can login to the application by replacing `public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationGroup> ApplicationGroups { get; set; }` with `public virtual ICollection<ApplicationGroup> ApplicationGroups { get; set; }` but the problem is after i do that i cannot use in built application group manager methods like `this.GroupManager.CreateGroupAsync(app);` anyone can help me with this.

this is my startup.Auth class

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            { 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you using OAuth JSON web token schema with Web API for login? If yes, try changing JSON encoding to form encoding while passing `grant_type=password` in content body (use `ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). AFAIK, JSON encoding works fine with `ICollection` but may not work with default implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler`.

Comment: yes, already did but not works.

Comment: cam you show your startup.cs

Comment: edit my question with startup.Auth.cs